# How to place photos in a grid

Tags: photoshop, image-alignment, grid

I have lots of photograph and I want to place them in a grid of my choice like 3x4 or 4x2 grid. And then place that grid on a sheet of 19 inch x 13 inch.

Example: [image]

Suppose this a sheet which is 13" x 14". And the grid is 4"x4".I want to place the photos in the grid and I also don't want the edges of the photos to coincide with edges of grid as in the above picture. There needs to be some padding or a border, but everything should come inside 4"x4" square. Then get a print of that sheet and cut the images along the grid lines.

When I had limited photos, I used to do this manually using Corel Draw, adjust each photo's position in a sheet of 13x19 inches. But now I have lots of them.

Is there any other software which I can use for this, or which can make this easy or automate it?

Comment: This sounds off-topic here, you should take a look at the software recommendation StackExchange website.

Comment: @Olivier: It's on-topic if the OP is asking about a way to present photographs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I tile pictures in a grid?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/18373/how-do-i-tile-pictures-in-a-grid)

Comment: @mattdm agreed that it's similar, but the suggested dupe doesn't seem to be oriented towards printing (I'm _assuming_), and the accepted answer suggests having to "fiddle" with row spacing. This question is pretty clearly about printing a contact sheet, or an uncut "wallet picture" sheet, without fiddling.

Comment: Is it common practice to cut photographies from a contact sheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a built-in feature of Photoshop, and has been for quite some time: say `File` → `Automate` → `Contact Sheet II`. It does exactly this.

Comment: Does the OP have access to PS?

Comment: @MichaelClark: The post is tagged `photoshop`.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a desk top publishing software thing, but since you mention padding and borders you probably know this already. I use Scribus to do something similar to create a poster of holiday photo's each year. It's free but not without it's quirks and certainly not automated.